# How can I simulate a moving average model(1) with parameter =0.7?

Tags: matlab, time-series

How can I simulate a ma(1) model with parameter =0.7 using matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Systems Identification Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/sysid/) may have what you need.

If you need or want to do it by hand, however (homework?), I would suggest outlining the steps of what needs to be done (break up the problem in parts, starting from the definition of MA models) and asking a more detailed question when you get stuck.