# simulate ARMA model with specific order and parameters value

Tags: matlab, time-series

What is the matlab function to simulate ARMA model and coda matlab function
(coda:convergence diagnostic and data analysis)

Answer (score 3):

A friendly suggestion: even normally helpful people will probably get annoyed if you ask too many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405622/how-can-i-simulate-a-moving-average-model1-with-parmeter-0-7) without indication that you're willing or able to do some work yourself. A better question might start with something like: "I tried x but it didn't work for reason y.."

As before, the [Systems Identification Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/sysid/) may have what you need.